# What id default value of variable in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

In the below-given code, if I run it with uncommented "SET @LossScenarioID = NULL" it will break but with commented "SET @LossScenarioID = NULL" it goes for an infinite loop. What is the value of the variable when we defined it and does it reset the value of the variable when we define it again as we are doing it here again in a loop? What is default value of a variable in SQL?

```
DECLARE @LossScenario AS TABLE
        (
              LossScenarioId INT
            , IsProcessed BIT
        )

    INSERT INTO @LossScenario
        (
              LossScenarioId
            , IsProcessed
        )
    Values ( 220, 0)
        , (221, 0)

    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @LossScenarioID INT

        --SET @LossScenarioID = NULL
        SELECT TOP 1 @LossScenarioID =  LossScenarioId
        FROM @LossScenario
        WHERE IsProcessed = 0


        IF @LossScenarioID IS NULL
        BEGIN
            BREAK
        END

        UPDATE @LossScenario
        SET IsProcessed = 1 
        WHERE LossScenarioId = @LossScenarioID
    END
```

Comment: The real question should be why are you using a loop? As for the default, the default in SQL, the language, is always null unless `NOT NULL` is specified. The loop itself is buggy though

Comment: Considering you `DECLARE` the variable `@LossScenarioID` in the `WHILE`, this would fail the moment it iterates more than once,.

Comment: Like @PanagiotisKanavos I also see no reason for a `WHILE`, that can never exit properly *(I honestly hate logic like `WHERE 1=1`, it's pointless...)*, here . Seems like a `INSERT INTO...SELECT` is all you need.

Comment: @Larnu this looks like another attempt to create a queue with SQL, hence the "worker loop". That's another thing that won't work like this

Comment: What's the point of this code? Is this an attempt to create a worker queue in the database? This code won't work, the problem isn't trivial and SQL Server already offers an implementation for this kind of queues with Message Broker.

Comment: On the other hand, if this is an attempt to create a queue container as if this was eg C#, it won't work and isn't needed to begin with. A table can work as a queue or stack simply by adding a sequential ID, or ensuring there's a valid order to begin with. Push can be a simple INSERT, Pop any operation that works on the row with MAX or MIN(ID).

Comment: Or one can use a CTE and get rid of row-by-row access entirely. What's the *actual* problem? What does this code really try to do?

Comment: Windowing functions like LEAD, LAG, FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE can be used to retrieve previous entries in an ordered set, removing the need for RBAR and queueing.

Comment: the same declaration of a variable is not "executed" multiple times (even within a loop). The loop will succeed just fine (even if the declare is in the loop)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am performing some operation based on this LossScenarioID and I am getting it as a comma-separated string. As I am not aware of worker-loop, I will learn it. I was not aware of the fact that declaration of variable is not executed multiple times so it was going in an infinite loop. It is a new thing for me and learning as I am writing more code. Thanks for teaching me a new thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2nd time round the loop, the `@LossScenarioID` variable does NOT automatically get re-initialized to NULL. And, if the TOP 1 query finds no matching results, that does NOT re-initialize the variable to NULL either. No assignment to the variable takes place - it will retain the previous ID it held, hence why it will continually loop.

This is expected, although I have seen this trip people up before! So you should definitely manually re-initialize the variable to NULL at the start of each iteration.

On a wider note, RBAR (Row-By-Agonizing-Row) operations should generally be avoided whenever possible, in favour of set-based approaches. You'll find better you get better performance, a more scalable solution, and avoid certain traps like this.

Comment: Another way to explain it: When the `@LossScenarioID` variable is declared for the first time, it's value is null. However, the next time control flows to the declare line  the variable will not be re-declared.

Comment: `DECLARE is not "executable" (at runtime). @variables are resolved/addressed/allocated before the execution starts (because execution depends on them). If the DECLARE is in a control-flow/statement, the @variable "exists" even if the control-flow statement is NOT executed at all: IF 1=2 BEGIN DECLARE @var INT; END SELECT @var = 1; SELECT @var;`

Comment: If I use " DECLARE @LossScenarioID INT  = NULL", will it be initialized in each loop?